# No specific subroutine for ‘mpi_scatter’

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran

I'm starting with MPI in Fortran and try to make an scatter from an array. This is the code:

```
program test_scatter
  use mpi
  implicit none
  integer                      :: ierr, rank, size, comm, i, j
  integer, parameter           :: dim = 5, dim_nodos = 4
  real, dimension(dim, dim)    :: panel_pos
  real, dimension(dim_nodos)   :: nodos
  real                         :: rev_buf

  forall(i = 1:dim_nodos) nodos(i) = i
  comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD
  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(comm, size, ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(comm, rank, ierr)

  call MPI_Bcast(panel_pos, dim*dim, MPI_REAL, 1, comm, ierr)
  call MPI_Scatter(nodos, 1, MPI_REAL, rev_buf, 1, 1, comm, ierr)
  print *, panel_pos, 'from rank', rank

  ! Finalizar MPI
  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end program test_scatter
```

I try to compile using:

```
mpif90 test_scatter.F90 -o test_scatter.e
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> call MPI_Scatter(nodos, 1, MPI_REAL, rev_buf, 1, 1, comm, ierr)
>                                                               1 
> Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_scatter’ at (1)
> ```

I have Debian testing. The system is up to date. I install OpenMPI like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-common openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: As your title possibly suggests a mis-understanding, it isn't "no subroutine" it's "no _specific_ subroutine".  In particular, you appear not to be giving the type on reciept.  Please carefully check your documentation.

Comment: You simply forgot the type of the received data. Your call should be `call MPI_Scatter(nodos, 1, MPI_REAL, rev_buf, 1, MPI_REAL, 1, comm, ierr)` (NB the extra `MPI_REAL`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, you need to additionally specify the `MPI_Datatype` of the receive buffer:

```
call MPI_Scatter(nodos, 1, MPI_REAL, rev_buf, 1, MPI_REAL, 1, comm, ierr)
```